# Ellipse definition

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

Spivak defines an ellipse as the set of points, the sum of whose distances from two fixed points is a constant. He takes these two points to be $(-c,0)$ and $(c,0)$ and the sum of the distances to be $2a$. He then derives $x^2/a^2 + y^2/(a^2-c^2) = 1$ and that 'clearly' we must choose $a>c$. Why must this choice be made?

Comment: If $a = c$, we get the line segment connecting the points. If $a < c$, then see whether there are any points at all such that the sum of the distances is $2a$ (use the triangle inequality).

Comment: Not really seeing where it's going sorry. 2(x+y) > sqrt((x+c)^2 + y^2) + sqrt((x-c)^2 + y^2) = 2a, so x+y>a needs to be satisfied......

Comment: For $p$ on the ellipse with foci $f_1,f_2$, we have $$2c = \lVert f_1 - f_2\rVert = \lVert (f_1 - p) - (f_2  - p)\rVert \leqslant \lVert f_1 - p\rVert + \lVert f_2 - p\rVert = 2a.$$ We have equality only if $p$ lies between the two foci.

Answer (score 3):

> Spivak defines an ellipse as the set of points, the sum of whose distances from two fixed points is a constant. He takes these two points to be $(-c,0)$ and $(c,0)$ and the sum of the distances to be $2a$.

If $a<c$, then the ellipse does not contain any points. Therefore, we must have $a\geq c$ for the definition to make sense. Further, if $a=c$, then the ellipse is the line segment from $(-c,0)$ to $(c,0)$, which may or may not be what you want. But the case $a=c$ can't be expressed by the equation, because the denominator $a^2-c^2$ would be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Well if

$a < c$

$a^2 < c^2$

$a^2-c^2 < 0 $

Let $a^2-c^2 = -d^2$

Equation would then be:

$x^2/a^2 - y^2/d^2 = 1$

A hyperbola

Comment: +1 but 'clearly' a hyperbola is not an ellipse :)